# Which test should I use if I want to see whether particular subset of the entire distribution is having higher value statistically?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, references

Given a collection of transactions tagged by branches/locations where the transaction is made.

Which test should I use to answer whether particular branch out perform the others or not in terms of transaction value.

It would be great if one can share reference/material of such test.

Comment: A higher value of what? And do you mean to just compare one sample to the rest of the samples?

Comment: @RickyB It can be different metric depending on the application. For instance you can consider the entire distribution is a collection of transactions tagged by branches/locations where the transaction is made. The question is whether particular branch out perform the others or not in terms of transaction value.

Comment: If you do it just once and for a predefined subset, then you can go with any suitable two-sample test, e.g. Wilcoxon's rank sum test. If you systematically want to screen for any "significantly different" subgroups, then it gets tricky.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_variance